# Keep the dynamic header constant after first load

Tags: javascript, dynamic

Our website's top navigation banner is dynamically loaded. Each user has a specific set of navigation tabs according to their access permission setting. And the banner in all pages for a specific user are all the same. So at the moment, our design is to use Ajax to get the user access permission setting and then populate the banner, which means when a user visits each page, the top banner refreshes after getting the Ajax data. This is not a good user experience of seeing the banner refreshes all the time. **What I want is that after logged in, the navigation banner should keep static apart from the color change for the active tab. Is there a way I can achieve this.** If the user's permission changed in the database, the user can hard load the page (or re-login)  to refresh the banner. By the way, the current top banner is in a separate HTML file. The page is all written in javascript, CSS, HTML. And no frameworks used in our website. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're aiming for, but if I understood correctly - why not just store the loaded header for the user in the database?

Comment: @EI_Vanja Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question. Please have a read again and see if it is clearer.  If I understand correctly, you are talking about keeping the banner html in local storage or indexDB. When each time to load  the file from there, wouldn't the banner be still refreshing. I can understand it will be quicker. But do you think it will be fast enough to be not noticeable to the user

Comment: I misunderstood your question originally (I though you needed to memorize one of several random headers). Now that I read it again, this really sounds like a job for php rather than js. Maybe someone more experienced will have a solution for just js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, anytime you navigate to a new page, no matter how efficient you make the loading, it will always be apparent on slower devices/connections. Ideally, your solution would be to either use an iframe (last resort) or to load the content dynamically and have it populate for each "page" within one real page via DOM manipulation. You can also use CSS to mask out elements or "pages" you don't want the user to see while they're on a current "page", which will allow it to already be loaded into the browser and you'd simply toggle it's visibility.

Browser requests to new pages automatically clear the document, which result in "flashes" between pages.

The easiest solution would be to have the elements populated via JavaScript through AJAX calls for the content/settings. I've attached a fiddle with an example of how to change content dynamically in vanilla JavaScript, all you'd need to do is load the content into the array and then update the elements (including the navigation for your tabs).

The relevant code for navigation would be here, but you could just set the page value to whichever tab they click. The code below swaps the visibility between two elements when the page changes based on whether or not a limit has been met:

```
  btn_prev.style.display = (curr_page > 1 ? "inline-block" : "none");
  btn_next.style.display = (curr_page < story.length ? "inline-block" : "none");
```

If you want to optimize it further, you could put the navigation buttons into an array and use each button's index so you don't need named elements.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0toz3L8/1/